Conditional Formatting starting and ending based upon cell values in a range
In a given range of x by y cells, I'm looking for a formula that will format cells in a row starting every time a cell value is "x" and ending  every time a cell value anywhere in the range is "x".
Here is an example of what I'd want it to look like:

The colors are not important.  They can all be the same color, but just so they are formatted.  So you can see, I have an x in B3, I want to format until I have an x in F4, and again until I have an x in H10.  And it should be row based as in the image, but within a range, as I will want apply this same logic to multiple ranges on the same page.  I hope this helps make it clear what I am after.

Is 'a' another value in the cells? If no, why two 'a's after some 'x's and not others? Can you maybe provide a screencap of what the final result should look like?

a is not meant to be a value, but an indictor.  I will add screenshot

it would be a lot easier to carry the X cells across the desired range and use a simple CF rule. I assume this is some kind of gantt chart and the colours indicate which person was engaged in some cpacity during a time slot.  For that kind of thing, type the data into the cells.

@teylyn - I guess I can do that.  It's probably fine.  Just increases the cognitive load.  This is for managing players during a soccer match, and it's hard to keep straight.

A solution proposal with a helper table. This helper table has the dimensions of the formatted area (B7:Q9 in the example). Formula in the auxiliary table (for B7 – copy for the whole range):
=IFERROR(XMATCH("x", $B3:B3, 0, -1), 0)

Conditional formatting formula (area B3:Q5, formula prepared for B3):
=B7=MAX(B$7:B$9)

In the B11:Q13 range, an illustration of how the conditional formatting formula works (this is not a part of the solution, but an illustration only).


This is awesome!  I know there  was a way to do it.  I just knew it was beyond me at the moment.
